# function to loop over users and insert in html

Tags: javascript, class

I would like to build a function that can loop over my objects that takes my users as parameter. Right now i have created a loop, which only takes the first user: henrik, but how can i make a function, where i can insert all the other users, as a parameter? hope you guys can give me some tips!

```
class User {
    constructor(firstname, lastname, age, gender, rightHanded){
        this.firstName = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.rightHanded = rightHanded;
    }
}
const henrik = new User("Henrik", "Thorn", 34, "male", true);
const hans = new User("Hans", "Thorn", 17, "male", true);
const jørgen = new User("jøren", "Thorn", 18, "male", true);
const liv = new User("liv", "Thorn", 17, "femal", true);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    let table = document.getElementById("personProfile");
    let html = "";
    let objectKeys = Object.keys(henrik);

    for (let objectKey of objectKeys) {
      html += "<tr><td>" + objectKey + "</td><td>" + henrik[objectKey] + "</td></tr>";
    }

    table.innerHTML = html;
});
```

Comment: I added an example to my answer: https://jsfiddle.net/myutga79/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, what you are looking for is a way to go through each user and have them render inside table.

```
class User {
    constructor(firstname, lastname, age, gender, rightHanded){
        this.firstName = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.rightHanded = rightHanded;
    }
}

const henrik = new User("Henrik", "Thorn", 34, "male", true);
const hans = new User("Hans", "Thorn", 17, "male", true);
const liv = new User("liv", "Thorn", 17, "femal", true);
const jorgen = new User("jøren", "Thorn", 18, "male", true);


function loadUsersOnHTML(users) {
    let html = "";
    users.forEach( user => {
        let table = document.getElementById("personProfile");
        for (let key in user) {
            html += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + user[key] + "</td></tr>";
        }
        table.innerHTML = html;
    })
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const users = [henrik, hans, jorgen, liv,];
    loadUsersOnHTML(users);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add all your users into an array:

```
const userArray = [];
userArray.push(new User("Henrik", "Thorn", 34, "male", true));
userArray.push(new User("Hans", "Thorn", 17, "male", true));
... etc
```

Then, you can iterate over each user

```
for (let user of userArray) {
   renderUser(user);
}
```

And then make a `renderUser` function that does your html and inserts it.

for example: https://jsfiddle.net/myutga79/